# How Can i Connect C#.net desktop application on My Computer to the MYSQL server of another computer

Tags: c#, mysql

currently i made C#.net application with MYSQL database connectivity. here it runs completely in my pc means in localhost.

But Now i want to move my database on other computer and doing same thing which is working with my localhost....

in short i want to connect my application with Remote MYSQL server

So What should i do????

my connection string is below

string connectionpath = "server=localhost;database=mydb;uid=root;password= admin";

what change i do?

Comment: The connection string says "localhost" - are you telling us that you haven't experimented with altering it?

Comment: i changed it with server ip address but it gives me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least a couple of things:

Set up your connection string to reference the server.

e.g.,

`string connectionString = "server=10.10.5.100;uid=theuser;password=thepassword;";`

And ensure that the user you are using has the correct privileges to be able to log in remotely.

It might be that you cannot log in remotely to certain accounts such as the admin (root) account.

Comment: how can i create a new account using root?

Answer (score 0):

Change

string connectionpath = "server={MyRemoteMachine};database=mydb;uid=root;password= admin";

where {MyRemoteMachine} is the ip or name of the remote server.

Comment: i tried this but that is not working...should i do any change in MYSQL configuration?